# It's possible overwrite DNS TTL with nginx headers?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ttl

My DNS provider doesn't allow me to set a custom TTL.

All my domains have a 300 (5 minutes) TTL, that is terrible low.

Can I send to browser a header from nginx with a custom TTL time to overwrite domain TTL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible overwrite DNS TTL with nginx headers, as nginx doesn't answer the DNS queries for your domain.

There should be no problem for you with the low TTL value. Why do you think that value is too low?

Comment: Because DNS need refresh every 5 minutes. To recurrent customers, they should query DNS resolve every 5 minutes and it takes about 20-30ms. Regular DNS TTL should be in 1 - 2 hours to a fine performance. Thanks!

Comment: That is true, but do you thing anybody will notice a 30ms delay? The TTL value is low, but that is probably because you are on a cloud platform where IP addresses are expected to change frequently.

Comment: The "problem" is because my IP is fixed, it "never" changes. My domain provider allow me to manage DNS, but I can not change the TTL values. 30ms is not an important delay, but I'm working on a high optimized connection website. My final solution will be change DNS provider to allow me to configure TTL :)